# What different moves can Professor Oak's Mew learn?

Tags: pokemon-masters

*Pokémon Masters* recently added Professor Oak as a playable character, with a Mew as his Sync Partner. One of their Passive Skills is "Oak's Research", for which the description is:

> Replaces some of the user's moves with different moves after using a sync move.

Is is known what these "different moves" are? Is there a set pool of moves Mew can learn through its Passive Skill, or can it randomly learn any move in the game - Lance's Hyper Beam, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Mew will learn fire blast, thunder and blizzard. All of them cost 3 move bars